# Добавление даты каждого дня года

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Есть таблица mysql в которую нужно залить тестовые данные для графика. График будет показывать динамику некоего значения в течении года, поэтому нужно что бы каждая строчка в таблице имела дату нового дня. например дата в первой строчке "22.07.2017" во второй "23.07.2017" и так далее - один день - одна строчка.
Написал небольшую хранимую процеду для этого :

```
delimiter //
create procedure `testHistoryUpload`()
begin
set @a = 0;
while (@a < 365)
do
insert into cashaccounts values 
(
'q111',
ROUND((RAND() * (100.22 - 10.93)) + 10.93),
ROUND((RAND() * (150.67 - 10.93)) + 10.93),
ROUND((RAND() * (10000.87 - 10.93)) + 10.93),
'24.07.2016'  // дата будет одна и та же
);
set @a=@a+1;
end while;
end//
```

Но никак не разберусь с датами. Подскажите кто знает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ найден. В цикле  вместо `'24.07.2016'` написать `adddate(now(), interval 1+@a day`.